# How do I improve my code?

Tags: java, performance

I've just started Java programming yesterday (so don't expect too much) and I've written some code. My code works the way i want it to work but there is obviously things wrong with it, i was just wondering ways in which to improve it. I think I've added unnecessary things. I'm practicing to use classes and other stuff.

the testing.java files contains:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class testing {
    private static Scanner input_sn;
    private static Scanner input_fn;
    private static Scanner input_mem;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String First_Name;
        String Second_Name;
        int members;
        int count;


        System.out.println("Members: ");
        input_mem = new Scanner(System.in);
        members = input_mem.nextInt();

        funcs funcsObj = new funcs();

        for (count = 0; count < members; count++)
        {
            System.out.println("What is the first name? ");
            input_fn = new Scanner(System.in);
            First_Name = input_fn.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is the second name? ");
            input_sn = new Scanner(System.in);
            Second_Name = input_sn.nextLine();

            funcsObj.names( funcsObj.setFn(First_Name), funcsObj.setSn(Second_Name));
        }   
    }
}
```

and my funcs.java file contains:

```
public class funcs
{
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private static int members = 0;

    public String setFn(String fn)
    {
        firstName = fn;
        return fn;
    }

    public String setSn(String sn)
    {
        secondName = sn;
        return sn;
    }


    public void names(String fn, String sn)
    {
        firstName = fn;
        secondName = sn;
        members++;
        System.out.printf("%d\t%s\t%s\n", members, fn, sn);
    }
}
```

I think most of the problems can be found in the funcs.java file.

Thanks

Comment: For this kind of question, stackoverflow's sister site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place.

Comment: *"but there is obviously things wrong with it"* - It's not that obvious.  If it "works the way you want it to" then how exactly is it "wrong"?

Comment: @EdS. probably it just feels wrong and kind of ugly, since there're several issues in it.

Comment: meaning, have i added unnecessary code, could i have done things quicker?

Comment: You need to ask specific questions on this forum

Comment: Is this a question like "i haven't written the code but that code doesn't work!"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names should be Capitalized.  EG: `ThisIsMyClassName`.  Field names should be camelCased. EG: `thisIsAFieldName`.  In java, you don't use underscores for field names.  You should put the opening curly braces on the same line as the statement.  EG: `if ... {` You can read more about these details in the java style guide:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html